# update table value

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table look like this image:

[image: this image reports_to_id is based on ID]

I want to create tree according this table. For example the top level person is admin and admin can see all employee details and if any person just down to admin he can see all employee details,  but not admin detail. I want to all details like this:

```
Admin

HZM

AZM

ZM

AM

sales and marketing
```

I want to create this type hierarchy, can you please help me to create this?

Comment: I want to create tree according this table

Answer (score 0):

What you can do here is use "levels." Example:

Level 100 - administrator
Level 90 - HZM
Level 80 - AZM
Level 70 - ZM
Level 60 - ZM
Level 50 - AM
Level 40 - sales and marketing

In the future you can add levels in between HZM and admin. For instance, you can use level 95.

By using numbers instead of names, you will be able to easily compare which users are allowed to do what.